# Prestashop Fatal error: Class 'FrontController' not found in

Tags: php, prestashop

Hi, i got this error message

> Fatal error: Class 'FrontController' not found in ../www/classes/controller/FrontController.php on line 28

I still can't figure it out what happened as I didn't touch the codes at all, except for templates for styling purposes.

Is there any file missing or wrong in the code?

I used this code in cpanel hosting and they are fine, but when I moved them to cloud hosting, it gives me that error.

Following the FronController.php Line 28

> class FrontControllerCore extends FrontController
>
> {   ---->Line28
>
> public $errors = array();

```
/**
 * @deprecated Deprecated shortcuts as of 1.5 - Use $context->var instead
 */
protected static $smarty, $cookie, $link, $cart;

public $iso;
```

Answer (score 0):

This file must be the original file from the PrestaShop distribution, but in your case it's not.

At the original file you have:

```
class FrontControllerCore extends Controller
```

Either remove the "Front" or get the original file and override that one.